# Err 401 Request Token Twitter (ASP)

Tags: twitter, oauth, asp-classic, request, token

Something go wrong and I don't know what, because I comprate with tool and the result is the same. The Tools and my code return the same Authorization Header , but twitter said: Failed to validate oauth signature and token

http://nouncer.com/oauth/authentication.html
http://nouncer.com/oauth/signature.html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" runat="server">
    /*
    * A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-1, as defined
    * in FIPS PUB 180-1
    * Version 2.1a Copyright Paul Johnston 2000 - 2002.
    * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
    * Distributed under the BSD License
    * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for details.
    */

    /*
    * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
    * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
    */
    var hexcase = 0;  /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase        */
    var b64pad = "="; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance   */
    var chrsz = 8;  /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode      */

    /*
    * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
    * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
    */
    function hex_sha1(s) { return binb2hex(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function b64_sha1(s) { return binb2b64(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function str_sha1(s) { return binb2str(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function hex_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2hex(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }
    function b64_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2b64(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }
    function str_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2str(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }

    /*
    * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working
    */
    function sha1_vm_test() {
        return hex_sha1("abc") == "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d";
    }

    /*
    * Calculate the SHA-1 of an array of big-endian words, and a bit length
    */
    function core_sha1(x, len) {
        /* append padding */
        x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - len % 32);
        x[((len + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = len;

        var w = Array(80);
        var a = 1732584193;
        var b = -271733879;
        var c = -1732584194;
        var d = 271733878;
        var e = -1009589776;

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
            var olda = a;
            var oldb = b;
            var oldc = c;
            var oldd = d;
            var olde = e;

            for (var j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                if (j < 16) w[j] = x[i + j];
                else w[j] = rol(w[j - 3] ^ w[j - 8] ^ w[j - 14] ^ w[j - 16], 1);
                var t = safe_add(safe_add(rol(a, 5), sha1_ft(j, b, c, d)),
                       safe_add(safe_add(e, w[j]), sha1_kt(j)));
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = rol(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = t;
            }

            a = safe_add(a, olda);
            b = safe_add(b, oldb);
            c = safe_add(c, oldc);
            d = safe_add(d, oldd);
            e = safe_add(e, olde);
        }
        return Array(a, b, c, d, e);

    }

    /*
    * Perform the appropriate triplet combination function for the current
    * iteration
    */
    function sha1_ft(t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < 20) return (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
        if (t < 40) return b ^ c ^ d;
        if (t < 60) return (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
        return b ^ c ^ d;
    }

    /*
    * Determine the appropriate additive constant for the current iteration
    */
    function sha1_kt(t) {
        return (t < 20) ? 1518500249 : (t < 40) ? 1859775393 :
         (t < 60) ? -1894007588 : -899497514;
    }

    /*
    * Calculate the HMAC-SHA1 of a key and some data
    */
    function core_hmac_sha1(key, data) {
        var bkey = str2binb(key);
        if (bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_sha1(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

        var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
            opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
        }

        var hash = core_sha1(ipad.concat(str2binb(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
        return core_sha1(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 160);
    }

    /*
    * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
    * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
    */
    function safe_add(x, y) {
        var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
        var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
        return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
    }

    /*
    * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
    */
    function rol(num, cnt) {
        return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
    }

    /*
    * Convert an 8-bit or 16-bit string to an array of big-endian words
    * In 8-bit function, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
    */
    function str2binb(str) {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (32 - chrsz - i % 32);
        return bin;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a string
    */
    function binb2str(bin) {
        var str = "";
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
            str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i >> 5] >>> (32 - chrsz - i % 32)) & mask);
        return str;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a hex string.
    */
    function binb2hex(binarray) {
        var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8 + 4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8)) & 0xF);
        }
        return str;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a base-64 string
    */
    function binb2b64(binarray) {
        var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3) {
            var triplet = (((binarray[i >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - i % 4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
                | (((binarray[i + 1 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 1) % 4)) & 0xFF) << 8)
                | ((binarray[i + 2 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 2) % 4)) & 0xFF);
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
                else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6 * (3 - j)) & 0x3F);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
</script>
<%

function normalizar(cadena)

normalizar=replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cadena,"^","%5E"),"&","%26"),"`","%60"),"{","%7B"),"}","%7D"),"|","%7C"),"]","%5D"),"[","%5B"),"""","%22"),"<","%3C"),">","%3E"),"\","%5C"),":","%3A"),"/","%2F"),"=","%3D")

end function


url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

web_ajax="http://localhost/cet/urbannews/modulo/twitter/ajax.asp"



m_strUserAgent="Test app"
m_strHost="api.twitter.com"

oauth_consumer_key = "fAEFB4ZX4fmBSAIkxLnkG6R0q"
oauth_consumer_sec = "a9Yi1C3Pfj6od5fee3GdII46nNqDQ9mDzpk4bqoGrumjisMWis"

oauth_nonce = Year(now) & Month(now) & Day(now) & Hour(now) & Minute(now) & Second(now) & Replace(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"),".","")
oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1"
oauth_timestamp = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
oauth_version = "1.0"

oauth_sign = "oauth_callback=" & replace(Server.urlencode(normalizar(web_ajax)),"%2E",".") & "&oauth_consumer_key=" & oauth_consumer_key & "&oauth_nonce=" & oauth_nonce & "&oauth_signature_method=" & oauth_signature_method & "&oauth_timestamp=" & oauth_timestamp & "&oauth_token=&oauth_version=" & oauth_version


response.Write oauth_sign & "<br /><br />"
oauth_sign =replace(replace(oauth_sign,"&","%26"),"=","%3D")
response.Write oauth_sign & "<br /><br />"
response.Write "POST&" & normalizar(url) & "&" & normalizar(oauth_sign) & "<br /><br />"

oauth_signature = b64_hmac_sha1(oauth_consumer_sec&"&", "POST&" & normalizar(url) & "&" & normalizar(oauth_sign))




response.Write oauth_consumer_key & "<br /><br />"
response.Write oauth_nonce & "<br />"
response.Write oauth_timestamp & "<br /><br />"
response.Write oauth_signature & "<br /><br />"



PARAM_AUTH="OAuth realm="""&url&""", oauth_callback=" & Server.urlencode(web_ajax) & ", oauth_consumer_key=""" & oauth_consumer_key & """, oauth_token="""", oauth_nonce=""" & oauth_nonce & """, oauth_timestamp=""" & oauth_timestamp & """, oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1"", oauth_version=""1.0"", oauth_signature=""" & normalizar(oauth_signature) & """"


response.write PARAM_AUTH& "<br /><br />"

Set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objSrvHTTP.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 15000, 15000
objSrvHTTP.Open "POST", url & "?oauth_callback=" & Server.urlencode(normalizar(web_ajax)), False
objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", PARAM_AUTH
objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", m_strUserAgent
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Host", m_strHost
objSrvHTTP.Send

response.Write objSrvHTTP.status & " - " & objSrvHTTP.statusText & " - " & url & "<br /><br />"
response.Write objSrvHTTP.responseText
Set objSrvHTTP = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Theres a classic asp library for Twitter here if it's any use to you http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2013/jun/asptwitter

Comment: I don't want ASPTwitter of other srcipt. I need to know what wrong. Any way, with ASPTwitter use a BearerToken this is only for read twitts not for write. ASPTwitter not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. Is my normalice function and other encode string. Now with that code work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" runat="server">
    /*
    * A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-1, as defined
    * in FIPS PUB 180-1
    * Version 2.1a Copyright Paul Johnston 2000 - 2002.
    * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
    * Distributed under the BSD License
    * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for details.
    */

    /*
    * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
    * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
    */
    var hexcase = 0;  /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase        */
    var b64pad = "="; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance   */
    var chrsz = 8;  /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode      */

    /*
    * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
    * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
    */
    function hex_sha1(s) { return binb2hex(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function b64_sha1(s) { return binb2b64(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function str_sha1(s) { return binb2str(core_sha1(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz)); }
    function hex_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2hex(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }
    function b64_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2b64(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }
    function str_hmac_sha1(key, data) { return binb2str(core_hmac_sha1(key, data)); }

    /*
    * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working
    */
    function sha1_vm_test() {
        return hex_sha1("abc") == "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d";
    }

    /*
    * Calculate the SHA-1 of an array of big-endian words, and a bit length
    */
    function core_sha1(x, len) {
        /* append padding */
        x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - len % 32);
        x[((len + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = len;

        var w = Array(80);
        var a = 1732584193;
        var b = -271733879;
        var c = -1732584194;
        var d = 271733878;
        var e = -1009589776;

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
            var olda = a;
            var oldb = b;
            var oldc = c;
            var oldd = d;
            var olde = e;

            for (var j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                if (j < 16) w[j] = x[i + j];
                else w[j] = rol(w[j - 3] ^ w[j - 8] ^ w[j - 14] ^ w[j - 16], 1);
                var t = safe_add(safe_add(rol(a, 5), sha1_ft(j, b, c, d)),
                       safe_add(safe_add(e, w[j]), sha1_kt(j)));
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = rol(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = t;
            }

            a = safe_add(a, olda);
            b = safe_add(b, oldb);
            c = safe_add(c, oldc);
            d = safe_add(d, oldd);
            e = safe_add(e, olde);
        }
        return Array(a, b, c, d, e);

    }

    /*
    * Perform the appropriate triplet combination function for the current
    * iteration
    */
    function sha1_ft(t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < 20) return (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
        if (t < 40) return b ^ c ^ d;
        if (t < 60) return (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
        return b ^ c ^ d;
    }

    /*
    * Determine the appropriate additive constant for the current iteration
    */
    function sha1_kt(t) {
        return (t < 20) ? 1518500249 : (t < 40) ? 1859775393 :
         (t < 60) ? -1894007588 : -899497514;
    }

    /*
    * Calculate the HMAC-SHA1 of a key and some data
    */
    function core_hmac_sha1(key, data) {
        var bkey = str2binb(key);
        if (bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_sha1(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

        var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
            opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
        }

        var hash = core_sha1(ipad.concat(str2binb(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
        return core_sha1(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 160);
    }

    /*
    * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
    * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
    */
    function safe_add(x, y) {
        var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
        var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
        return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
    }

    /*
    * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
    */
    function rol(num, cnt) {
        return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
    }

    /*
    * Convert an 8-bit or 16-bit string to an array of big-endian words
    * In 8-bit function, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
    */
    function str2binb(str) {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
            bin[i >> 5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (32 - chrsz - i % 32);
        return bin;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a string
    */
    function binb2str(bin) {
        var str = "";
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
            str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i >> 5] >>> (32 - chrsz - i % 32)) & mask);
        return str;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a hex string.
    */
    function binb2hex(binarray) {
        var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8 + 4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((3 - i % 4) * 8)) & 0xF);
        }
        return str;
    }

    /*
    * Convert an array of big-endian words to a base-64 string
    */
    function binb2b64(binarray) {
        var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3) {
            var triplet = (((binarray[i >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - i % 4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
                | (((binarray[i + 1 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 1) % 4)) & 0xFF) << 8)
                | ((binarray[i + 2 >> 2] >> 8 * (3 - (i + 2) % 4)) & 0xFF);
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
                else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6 * (3 - j)) & 0x3F);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
</script>
<%
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"



        Public Function EncodeString(s)
            Dim strTmpVal : strTmpVal = s
            Dim strRetVal : strRetVal = ""
            Dim intAsc : intAsc = 0
            Dim strHex : strHex = ""
            Const OAUTH_UNRESERVED = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~"

            Dim i, strChr : For i = 1 To Len(strTmpVal)
                strChr = Mid(strTmpVal, i, 1)

                If InStr(1, OAUTH_UNRESERVED, strChr) = 0 Then
                    intAsc = Asc(strChr)

                    If intAsc < 32 Or intAsc > 126 Then
                        'strHex = encodeURIComponent(strChr)
                    Else
                        strHex = "%" & Hex(intAsc)
                    End If

                    strRetVal = strRetVal & strHex
                Else
                    strRetVal = strRetVal & strChr
                End If
            Next

            EncodeString = strRetVal
        End Function

url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
web_ajax="https://www.mydomain.com/my-callback.html"




m_strUserAgent="Test app asp"
m_strHost="api.twitter.com"
m_metodo="POST"


oauth_consumer_key = "fAEFB4ZX4fmBSAIkxLnkG6R0q"
oauth_consumer_sec = "a9Yi1C3Pfj6od5fee3GdII46nNqDQ9mDzpk4bqoGrumjisMWis"

oauth_nonce = Year(now) & Month(now) & Day(now) & Hour(now) & Minute(now) & Second(now) & Replace(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"),".","")
oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1"
oauth_timestamp = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
oauth_version = "1.0"

oauth_sign = "oauth_callback=" & EncodeString(web_ajax) & "&oauth_consumer_key=" & oauth_consumer_key & "&oauth_nonce=" & oauth_nonce & "&oauth_signature_method=" & oauth_signature_method & "&oauth_timestamp=" & oauth_timestamp & "&oauth_version=" & oauth_version


response.Write oauth_sign & "<br /><br />"
response.Write m_metodo & "&" & EncodeString(url) & "&" & EncodeString(oauth_sign) & "<br /><br />"

oauth_signature = b64_hmac_sha1(oauth_consumer_sec&"&", m_metodo & "&" & EncodeString(url) & "&" & EncodeString(oauth_sign))




'response.Write oauth_consumer_key & "<br /><br />"
response.Write oauth_nonce & "<br />"
response.Write oauth_timestamp & "<br /><br />"
response.Write oauth_signature & "<br /><br />"


PARAM_AUTH="oauth_callback=" & EncodeString(web_ajax) & "&oauth_consumer_key=" & oauth_consumer_key & "&oauth_nonce=" & oauth_nonce & "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" & oauth_timestamp & "&oauth_version="&oauth_version&"&oauth_signature=" & EncodeString(oauth_signature)


response.write PARAM_AUTH& "<br /><br />"
response.write "<br /><br />INFO POST<br /><br />"

requesturl=url & "?" & PARAM_AUTH


response.write "<br /><b>URL: </b>" & url
response.write "<br /><br /><b>Request URL: </b>" & requesturl
response.write "<br /><br /><b>Content-Type: </b>" & "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
response.write "<br /><br /><b>Authorization: </b>" & PARAM_AUTH
response.write "<br /><br /><b>User-Agent: </b>" & m_strUserAgent
response.write "<br /><br /><b>Host: </b>" & m_strHost

response.write "<br />RESPONSE: <br /><br />"

Set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
'objSrvHTTP.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 15000, 15000
objSrvHTTP.Open m_metodo, requesturl, False
objSrvHTTP.setOption(2)=13056
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", m_strUserAgent
objSrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Host", m_strHost
objSrvHTTP.Send

response.Write objSrvHTTP.status & " - " & objSrvHTTP.statusText & "<br />"
response.Write objSrvHTTP.responseText
Set objSrvHTTP = Nothing


%>
```